# Depth of Field in 2.68?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I can't get "depth of field" to work as expected in version 2.68. Here are the steps I'm taking (from a brand new file):

1. I clone the default cube a few times, and place all the cubes in a row.
2. I go to the camera's settings, and select a cube on which to focus in the "Depth of Field" section.
3. I switch to compositing mode and check the "use nodes" box.
4. I add a "Defocus" node in between the "Render Layers" node and the "Composite" node.
5. I also connect the "Z" output from the "Render Layers" node to the "Z" input of the "Defocus" node.
6. I render. When the image finally goes through the compositing process, I can see the cubes, and blurring occurs, but the camera is NOT focused on the cube I selected in the camera settings.

I've tried this both in the Blender internal renderer and in Cycles. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As [described here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1563/290), you also need to enable "Use Z-Buffer".

Comment: Adrik, I think your suggestion was the one that worked. Can you submit it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Since the answer there works and the issues are pretty much the same. It is now basically a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why, but it seems that using an object as a focal point only works when using an *Empty*.

[image]

## Cycles:

(Note that cycles will render with DoF without the need for composite nodes.)

[image]

Setting *Blades* to 3 or more makes it possible to render with a non-circular aperture (this setting refers to the number of "blades" in the camera's [aperture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture))

[image]

## Blender Internal:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Note this answer is specifically relating to Blender Internal. However, the main concepts can be used in Cycles as well*.

Setting up the defocus node can take a little bit of practice (and trial and error), but the main issue is the distance. I personally would recommend using fStop settings, because I think fStop makes more sense (you can use fStop if you check *Use Z-Buffer*).

Using the same setup as you mentioned in your question, change the fStop distance until it looks good (probably around 6).

fStop at 0.0:
[image: fstop 0]

fStop at 4.0:
[image: fstop 4]

fStop at 10.0:
[image: fstop at 10]

You can also tweak the threshold of the blur and the maximum amount of blur allowed.