# Output Z-Pass in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am trying to get Z Pass to render but all I get is a white image. Any ideas why that happens?

I tried setting up the render layers, checked only z-pass since that's all I need but still can't get it going. I am having a similar issue when trying to output to PNG's other passes but they do show up however at least in the viewer.

Also I tried looking up for tuts on this but what I found is only for internal compositor unfortunately.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the compositor is the same regardless of the render engine used. What do you mean by "only for internal compositor"?

Comment: I mean they are for the blender compositor not others such as after effects, nuke which are external.

Comment: Oh. sorry, I misunderstood. Does the [solution here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1563/599) work for you?

Comment: If you really want to output Z pass, you may consider to use other format that can store Z-buffer data, like OpenEXR. I don't think a real Z-buffer can be kind of visible data, though can be shown in UV/Image Editor.