# How do I focus the camera on a certain area or object?

Tags: rendering, camera

I was working on a scene and the camera moved pretty fast in it that you couldn't even see the object in it. So I would like to know how you focus the blender camera on an object so that when the camera moves fast you can see that object clearly.

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender render? In which way you are controlling the focus? Are you using Depth of Field, Motion blur, Zoom blur or any compositing node setup that involves camera's focus? Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18386/can-i-control-depth-of-focus-v-depth-deph-of-field

Comment: I think you mean that the camera has to look at the object continuously, depending on its movement?

Answer (score 2):

## Tracking

I think the term you wanted to use is "tracking". Focus refers to whether the camera is in-focus or blurred.

1. Select your Camera
2. From the Constraints context add a Damped Track Constraint
3. Set the Target to be your object you want the Camera to follow
4. Set the axis to -Z (that's the direction the Camera looks out of)

[image: Camera tracking a cube]

## Focus

If you want to set the camera's focus, (as in blur), add an Empty to your scene, then from your Camera settings specify that the Empty is to be used to specify the point of focus. Position the Empty accordingly. Adjust the F-Stop to control the amount of blur.

[image: Depth of Field focus settings - use an Empty]

Comment: How do you in-focus the camera on the object so background is blurred?

Comment: @AustinH. Please see the update to my answer.