# Bokeh or defocus in Blender's default render engine?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to do Bokeh or defocus or anything of the sort in Blender's default render engine?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/depth-of-field-is-not-being-rendered-in-blender-internal and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/depth-of-field-in-2-68

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I focus the camera on a certain area or object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39152/how-do-i-focus-the-camera-on-a-certain-area-or-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Depth of field is not being rendered in Blender Internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/depth-of-field-is-not-being-rendered-in-blender-internal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Depth of Field" tab under the render settings has the controls for the dof, but in order for anything to happen you need to also go to the compositor and add a "defocus" node, and be sure to plug not just the image into the image socket, but also the Z value into the Z socket, and make sure "Use Z Buffer" is enabled..  Then you can play around with the f-stop value in the node till you get a result you're happy with.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured it out. If you want, I can share the final output of what I was working on when it's finished. (It's just some low-poly art I was trying to do.)

Comment: @OfficialRCO yay!

Answer (score 1):

If you select your camera, and go to the camera tab on the properties bar, there should be a **Depth of Field** tab.
[image]

You can change the object that will be the focus point, or you can input a distance instead. Change the value of F-Stops to achieve the Depth of Field/Blur effect you're going for.
As for Bokeh, tick the **High-Quality** box and you can change the number of blades to whatever bokeh effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I will say I tried that and nothing happened but I'll look into it some more. Thanks.

Comment: This won't do anything without some compositing nodes.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I figured it out.