# Reverse effect of Defocus node?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying to reverse the effect of the Defocus node as shown below :

[image]

As you can see the Front is being blurred and the back is focused , is it possible for the front to be focused instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a vector **normalize** node and a **color ramp** before the Z input on the defocus node. Playing with the sliders on the color ramp you should be able to find the point where you want to focus.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/blender-cycles-manual-dof/8133#8133

Answer (score 4):

In camera properties tab alter the focus distance.