# Blender 2.76b Depth of Field doesn't work

Tags: depth-of-field

[image]

Blender 2.76b Depth of Field doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have "Compositing" checked in the "Post Processing" panel in the Render Settings?

Comment: related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/depth-of-field-f-stop-not-doing-anything and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/depth-of-field-in-2-68/1930#1930 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30918/reverse-effect-of-defocus-node

Comment: I have try it all, but it dosn't work.

Comment: Have you made or selected a Focus object in the 'Depth of Field' panel and set a distance value under the D.o.F. box?

Comment: Yes, I do. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have "Use Nodes" checked in the Compositor? Also try increasing the "Focal Length" of the Camera.

Comment: It could be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the camera at the top of window containing the Depth of Field tab is actually set to your active camera. I had the exact same problem.