# Change DOF Focal point in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

Greetings to everyone from Chile! I am submerging in Blender world since a few week and probably I am dragging a little inertia habit from Nuke and After Effects trying to composing DOF from a Multilayer EXR sequence with Z pass.

I made a very simple scene in Blender (a pack of textured boxes) and I acheived a nice DOF in Compositor setting the camera focus in an Empty object (to have freedom of displace focus at my discretion) and using the Defocus node. My problem start when I try to change that focus plane in Composition once scene is rendered. In Nuke and After Effects i could do that in a straightforward way.

Because of the short time i am inside Blender i can't figure how to do that, or simply consider that Blender have just a different approach to get the effect.

A little light in this dark corner would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30918/reverse-effect-of-defocus-node/30919#30919https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30918/reverse-effect-of-defocus-node/30919#30919