# Why do my object looks out of focus?

Tags: animation, objects, camera

I'm kinda new to Blender and I was asked for help for my event to make an animation. I want to make something like a box falling from the sky. I went through some tutorials and i did make it right. What is not right is, the object (which is a box with a rigidbody) quite not in focus as in a camera. Here's the screenshot of the object showing it's out-of-focus.

[image: out of focus]

How do i make the image to be in focus in such way that the object didn't look like it's being blurred by the camera?

Comment: Focus called Depth of field in Blender. You can adjust its distance in the camera properties or turn off it in the render settings.

Comment: Read: [How do I set focus range](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99163/how-do-i-set-focus-range/99417#99417)

Comment: I did that, and nothing happen. The box still out of focus.