# Depth of field fail

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

Hi im tryng to play with depth of field to look more realistic, but I don't see that nothing changes... I'm playing with distance and F Stop.
[image]

Only I see that makes all blury and pixelated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

The first is 60 FStop and the second one 1 FStop.

I try o change those parameters, but due to the rendering of the prewiew is too slow I can not see diferences. (I have 32 GB RAM)

[image]

[image]

Is like only foucs the floor, I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a wide lens (39mm) with a long focus distance (11m).
Even at *f/1* the depth of field is 5 meters wide which still covers most of your scene.

Either use longer lens, or shorter focus distance.
You can check your DoF here: https://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html

You can preview the depth of field in viewport:
[image]

<sup>39mm compared to 135mm lens with f/1 and focus at 6 meters</sup>

[image]
[image]

Note that you can also use a *f*-stop that is less than 1.0

A different way to get selective focus, with the exact same field of view, is to use a much larger sensor size, which in turn will make you use a longer lens to have the same field of view, hence making the focusing distance more critical and with less depth of field. For example, if you make the sensor twice as large, you will need a lens that is also twice as large for the same field of view.

Read:

[How do I set focus range?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99163/how-do-i-set-focus-range/99417#99417)

Also, when it comes to depth of field it is important to work in real world dimensions. If the objects are larger than in real life, then your distances to the camera will be much larger, making it hard to get selective focus.

Comment: Hi may I ask you another question?

Comment: thanks bro, your links help me a lot to understand it. But is that it frustrates me a lot having to wait for the rendering of the preview to see how it affects the changes I make in the FStop and the distances... I edited the question above... If you can give me some tips. Or I could upload the archive.

Comment: SOLVED. I play with low FStop. 1.8-0.9 Thanks