# Fake DOF in the Compositor

Tags: rendering, workflow, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

You see, I had a very long render of about 5 hours. And in the end I found out that I totally forgot to add depth of field. So now I am thinking of a way to do that: either outside blender or in blender. I should probably be able to do something in compositor.

**Does anybody know if there is a way I can fake depth of field in compositor?**

(p.s. I have no object passes)

Answer (score 3):

In order to get **realistic** *Depth of Field* a 2d [Depth Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map) is always required:

[image]

I'd recommend duplicating the scene, enable the 'Z pass' (*Scene > Passes*) and **rerender** the scene via *Material Override*. Use a simple material, set the *Samples* to *1* and follow the instructions of this answers: [How can I get a Depth of field render pass?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-get-a-depth-of-field-render-pass)

[image]