# How to make a brush (alpha image) using Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, sculpting

I wonder how to render an alpha image to use for sculpting mode.
This alpha image is called Height Map images.

[image: This is Height Map image for bas relief]

[image: Adding this image as texture for sculping]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you want. Have you tried doing this? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How can I get a Depth of field render pass?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-get-a-depth-of-field-render-pass)

Comment: Is the edit poor made consistent with what you're wanting?

Comment: I have added images in order to understand my question.

Comment: Okay, I thought those where images that poor added. Good to see that they're yous.

Comment: @TARDISMaker 'Sculpting' tag added, 'Blender Cycles' removed from title (tagged with cycles already, so there is no need to have it in the title), see revision No. 3: http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/46620/revisions

Comment: @poor Okay, yeah. I asked because when I made my first look at the revisions it looked like you added the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Render out the image. The lights and materials don't matter.

In the compositor add a normalize node and drop the z pass through that. This will make the lowest value 0, and the highest 1 while mapping the rest through that.

Then with the RGB Curves node, switch the handles so that they are inverted (left being on the top, and right on the bottom), and add a handle in the middle and adjust it until you're happy with the result.

[image] 
*The finished node setup should look something like that*

Comment: It looks like you are using an orthographic projection too right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessary, of course.