# Render Z Depth Pass as PNG? (render becomes completely white?!)

Tags: rendering, camera

How do I render a Z Depth Pass as PNG without everything in the scene becoming white? Everything in my Z Depth Pass-render that's farther away than 1 meter or so becomes completely white... Is there any way to set the Z Depth Pass range, so the things closest to the camera becomes black and only the thing that's the furthest away from the camera becomes white?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49892/z-depth-pass-in-cycles-rendering-white and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43009/1245. Z-buffer pass can't be previewed in viewer by default since it's providing values from 0 to infinity while only 0 to 1 makes sense to viewer and display. *"How do I render a Z Depth Pass as PNG"* you don't render it in PNG as it will clip everything above 1 (although if your scene is no bigger than 1 blender unit it might work maybe). Render to OpenEXR and use it

Comment: It won't be a Z pass anymore if you clip and normalize.

Comment: Agree with rjg, render exr's to get a proper Z-pass / information:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49892/z-depth-pass-in-cycles-rendering-white#comment85028_49892